# Get values from object array w/o looping through it

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object array like below, is it possible to grab the values of name property without looping through it.

```
var objArray = [ { name: 'APPLE', type: 'FRUIT' },
                 { name: 'ONION', type: 'VEGETABLE' } ]
```

will it be feasible to grab the values of name as CSV (APPLE,ONION) without looping though it. Fundamentally a helper function which takes this object array as input and outputs the CSV of the given property and in this case it is name.

Comment: How do expect to traverse the array without some kind of loop? You could manually access at index.

Comment: One option would be to create your own reusable function to do this

Comment: Why not loop through it?

Comment: There is no way you can do it ...you have to loop it

Comment: @tcooc this is just a small object array and i may need to handle large number of object arrays whose length might also be large so looking for a way to do it w/o looping.

Comment: @Sai To clarify, you don't want `for` or `while` loops, but function calls are ok?

Comment: @tcooc yep function calls are ok

Comment: `objArray.map(o => o.name).join()` but this also uses loops internally

Comment: Looks like every other option uses looping. @Andreas this is pretty cool, i'm trying to use the syntax in a CLI, so wondering if there are any restrictions with regards to compatibility

Comment: You can upload the data to the graphics card with what little API is exposed to javascript and use a vector processor or parallel execution there. Tip: It's not gonna be what you'd like to have, certainly a lot more code than a loop and probably also slower due to overhead of copying back and forth. Also some limitations might apply (stringlength). Otherwise, on a cpu, being singlethreaded in javascript, this is logically impossible.

Comment: `... => ...` is ES6 syntax. `objArray.map(function(o) { return o.name }).join()` would be the vanilla version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **map()** and / or **reduce()**

```js
var objArray = [
  { name: 'APPLE', type: 'FRUIT' },
  { name: 'ONION', type: 'VEGETABLE' }
];

var csvString = objArray
                   .map(function(item){ return item.name; })
                   .join();

// ===================
// es6 version of the above
// ===================
// var csvString = objArray.map((item) => item.name).join();
// ===================

console.log(csvString)
```

If you control the data formatting, and there are **"lots"** of items to process then there are more effective ways to structure things.  If this fails your performance testing then you might look at storing the data as

```
var obj = {
    "APPLE": { name: 'APPLE', type: 'FRUIT' },
    "ONION": { name: 'ONION', type: 'VEGETABLE' }
};
```

Then test the performance of:

```
Object.keys(obj).join()
```

Once the *key* is set to the name it would be upto you to determine if that made the inner name redundant or if the inner objects were needed at all if there are only the two data elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own function to do this, although it will have to iterate through the array, such as:

```
function namesCSV(arr){
    var toReturn = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
         toReturn += arr[i].name;
         if(i != array.length-1){
             toReturn += ",";
         }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just the built-in [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to get values:

```js
var objArray = [ { name: 'APPLE', type: 'FRUIT' },
                 { name: 'ONION', type: 'VEGETABLE' } ]

objArray.forEach(function(obj) {
  // work with obj
  console.log(obj.name);
});
```